# The history of the use of "man"

Tags: pronouns, history, word-usage, generic

The pronoun 'he' used generically, as well as a lot of words including "man-kind" or generic "man" are sex-biased and are not acceptable. However, not so long ago, they were the proper used terms for describing the general. For example, "Man must adjust to his environment." or "He that loves must forgive." etc. Was this always the case or did there use to be a difference in terms between male and female?

Comment: I wonder why anyone would down-vote this question, unless they disliked the idea of gender-neutral language.

Comment: "no longer acceptable" --> instant downvote, stopped reading further.

Comment: Why do you say that _mankind_ is sex-biased and not acceptable? Is it just your opinion or not?

Comment: @Lo'oris: it is often better to challenge the assumptions in the question in an answer, than just to downvote.

Comment: It is true. It is now no longer appropriate to use the term "fireman", "firefighter" has to be used instead.

Comment: @Third Idiot: I didn't know it, but it seems you were right, I posted some material I found.

Comment: Spelling does not imply sexism of the speaker. Because we use the term "man-kind" to include everyone does not imply some kind of bias, it's just a word that has multiple meanings, one which includes women.

Comment: It apparently is politically incorrect language, sexist, and therefore offensive. Maybe you accept using "mankind" and "man-made", but it is offensive to feminists.

Comment: @Third Idiot: I'm male - so according to some, I'm automatically biased. But I really do think objecting to *man-made* as sexist is a bit ott. Not quite so bad as complaining about lack of media coverage for the world heavyweight **female** boxing champion, but heading in that direction.

Comment: @Third: That may be so, but political correctness is considered bad taste by a great many people, who will happily persist in using *-man* to indicate both men and women, just like *he*. Don't be fooled by loud complainers into believing that everybody thinks their way. They are evil, ugly prescriptivists trying to corrupt your soul by foisting moral guilt upon you.

Comment: Voting to close on account of this will probably just end up being a focus for soap-boxing

Comment: I agree with Lo'oris; I have never downvoted a question before on any Stack Exchange website but being told that perfectly normal English usage is "unacceptable" is unacceptable.

Comment: The tone of this question is just a little too argumentative for my taste. Closing.

Comment: @Cerberus, great comment. I agree that the use of gender-neutral language is unnecessary and bothersome, but I was only asking a history question, and many people got offended?

Comment: However, for all the dissenting people out there, this question is not subjective nor argumentative because it is asking for the history of the generic pronoun"he", and its usage. Also, if you believe that there is no problem with sexism in language, there are people including [this](http://jerz.setonhill.edu/writing/style/gender.html)

Comment: So true was it said," One man's euphemism is another man's insult!"

Comment: @Brian Hooper,nohat here's a [link for you.](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/56779382/GENDER-NEUTRAL-LANGUAGE-IN-OFFICIAL-AND-LEGAL-DOCUMENTS)

Comment: @Brian Hooper @nohat @FumbleFingers @Third Idiot.  This needed editing NOT closing. It is actually a reasonable question. Some people are too quick to downvote / close threads, it seems arrogant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll paste you two passages about usage of "mankind" and "man" from my NOAD. It seems you were right, usage has changed for "politically correct" reasons:

> **USAGE of "man"**
>   Traditionally, the word **man** has been used to refer not only to adult males but also to human beings in general, regardless of sex. There is a historical explanation for this: in Old English, the principal sense of **man** was ‘a human being,’ and the words **wer** and **wif** were used to refer specifically to ‘a male person’ and ‘a female person,’ respectively. Subsequently, **man** replaced **wer** as the normal term for ‘a male person,’ but at the same time the older sense ‘a human being’ remained in use.
>
> In the second half of the 20th century, the generic use of **man** to refer to ‘human beings in general’ (*reptiles were here long before man appeared on the earth*) became problematic; `the use is now often regarded as sexist or old-fashioned.` In some contexts, terms such as **the human race** or **humankind** may be used instead of **man** or **mankind**. However, in other cases, particularly in compound forms, alternatives have not yet become established: there are no standard accepted alternatives for manpower or the verb man, for example.

Then:

> **USAGE of suffix -man**
>   Traditionally, the form **-man** was combined with other words to create a term denoting an occupation or role, as in **fireman**, **layman**, **chairman**, and **mailman**. As the role of women in society has changed, with the result that women are now more likely to be in roles previously held exclusively by men, many of these terms ending in **-man** have been challenged as sexist and out of date. As a result, there has been a gradual shift away from **-man** compounds except where referring to a specific male person.
>
> Gender-neutral terms such as **firefighter** and **mail carrier** are widely accepted alternatives. And new terms such as **chairperson**, **layperson**, and **spokesperson**, which only a few decades ago seemed odd or awkward, are common today.

Comment: Uh? Why downvote?

Answer (score -4):

The generic pronoun *he* wasn't always generic. It was actually the result of skilled political lobbying in the nineteenth century. In 1850, the British Parliament passed the Interpretation Act 1850, also called Lord Brougham's Act, which made the pronoun *he* universal to include both male and female. The reasoning behind this was apparently due to the usage of the word *man*.

Man has always meant humans in general, ever since it evolved from the German word *mannaz*.

*He* hasn't always been generic. *Man* has.

However, in view of the women in this world, we must not leave them out. This has come under scrutiny in the late 20th century, and now women are being included in everything, hence the inappropriateness of using *he* as a generic term. Instead of *he*, *they* is used instead to avoid sexist language.

Also, the Interpretation Act 1850 has been superseded by the Interpretation Act 1978 out of deference for women.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:United_Kingdom_Acts_of_Parliament_1850

http://interpretation-act-1850.co.tv/

Comment: This answer is wrong and a misrepresentation. It is true that in most uses "he" is not, and never was generic. But indefinite "he" (e.g. "He that hath eares to heare, let him here") could always comprise either sex. In legal and parliamentary documents it was felt necessary to spell this out, (but until very recently this was not usual in ordinary contexts). This led to extra wordage in parliamentary papers, and the avowed purpose of the Interpretation Act 1850 was to "shorten the language", not make any kind of political point.